# How to add octicons as font similar to atom

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, atom-editor

How do I add octicons as font similar to the way atom did it?

Whilst inspecting the atom codebase I discovered that they are using the octicon icon set as font (`font-family: 'Octicons Regular'` & `content: "\f0a4"`). How would I implement the set in such a way to my own project? Is there a public release?

The following picture is a screenshot of the atom src showing the styles. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: are you implementing via html and css or is there a framework like Node.js?

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi I dont understand why this would be relevant. However I do have a nodejs backend & build my frontend with webpack. The frontend is written in an custom framework (similar to angular)

Comment: For if you have npm, I thought of package [typefaces](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typefaces) as a solution. But again availability `Octicons` is a doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no available CDNs for **Octicons Regular** so you have to get your own WebFontkit. Then you have to add the fonts using `@font-face` parameter.

Follow the below steps to add custom fonts to your HTML:-

**1. Download the Octicons font:-** The Octicons Regular fonts are available in this [link.](https://github.com/tony/dot-fonts/tree/master/awesome-terminal-fonts) Download the TrueType Font file format (.ttf).

**2. Create a WebFont Kit:-** Upload the downloaded (.ttf) file to [WebFontkit Generator.](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Then download the optimal WebFontkit.

**3. Extract and Upload the font files to your hosted site:-** Edit the ***stylesheet.css*** file to update the url. For instance if you have url like, `www.example.com`. So your .css file after update woluld look like:-

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Octicons";
src: url("https://example.com/css/fonts/Octicons.woff") format("woff"),
url("https://example.com/css/fonts/Octicons.woff2") format("woff2")
}
```

**4. Use Octicons font in your CSS declarations:-** As you have added css fonts to your site you can use this in your CSS declarations. For e.g,

```
p {
font-family: Octicons;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```